# ADFS 2.0 without authentication agent

Tags: winforms

Is there any possibility to integrate to ADFS 2.0 without having to program authentication agent, or program Radius client in .net

Is it possible to get more information or demo on the ADFS integration with SecureId OTP?

If not available, how much would it cost to get a .net or COM API accessible from .net in order to authenticate programmatically?